# How to Optimize query of substring searching in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have 2 tables both as the same form

**table A :**   `content | text`

**table B :**   `SubContent | text`

Table B containing substring Of Texts in Table A

**for exampale:**

Table a :

- zupta . . for **making south africa** worse than ever .
- zur eda **terkenang arwah ibu** . . eda terkenang arwah ibu . .

Table B :

- **making south africa**
- **terkenang arwah ibu**

what i want to achive is :

```
making south africa | zupta . . for **making south africa** worse than ever.
terkenang arwah ibu | zur eda **terkenang arwah ibu** . . eda terkenang arwah ibu . .
```

the query I used is very simple

```
select subcontent, content from A join B on  content SIMILAR TO '%'||subcontent||'%'
```

the query explain :

```
Gather  (cost=1000.00..6611032.19 rows=1678309 width=180)
  Workers Planned: 2
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..6442201.29 rows=699295 width=180)
"        Join Filter: (A.content ~ similar_escape((('%'::text || B.subcontent) || '%'::text), NULL::text))"
        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on A  (cost=0.00..8675.79 rows=186479 width=91)
        ->  Seq Scan on B  (cost=0.00..19.50 rows=750 width=89)
```

i try use **Large Text Indexes**  follow by this blog (Andrew Kane done a great job! )

https://medium.com/@ankane/large-text-indexes-in-postgres-5d7f1677f89f

**i try to add an index on both of the columns**  that didn't help the execution takes 40 minutes, any ideas?

explain after using Laurenz Albe answer

```
Nested Loop  (cost=27.79..100352.93 rows=1678309 width=180)
  ->  Seq Scan on q2_distinct  (cost=0.00..19.50 rows=750 width=89)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on clean_distinct  (cost=27.79..111.40 rows=2238 width=91)
"        Recheck Cond: (A.content ~ similar_escape((('%'::text || q2_distinct.part) || '%'::text), NULL::text))"
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "clean_distinct_Post content_idx"  (cost=0.00..27.23 rows=2238 width=0)
"              Index Cond: (A.content ~ similar_escape((('%'::text || B.content) || '%'::text), NULL::text))"
```

Comment: Show us create table

Comment: its really trivial but here you go **create table A
(
 content text
);**  same goes for B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any join that does not have a join condition with an equality operator (`=`) can only use a nested loop join.

The only index that can potentially help here is a trigram index on `A`:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX ON "A" USING gin (content gin_trgm_ops);
```

But you shouldn't expect to get good execution times with a query like that.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres' in-built [textsearch functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-textsearch.html) could help here. But you will need to add a second column to table A to help index it. You will also need to know the language of each string in table A.

Example query.

```
postgres=# select to_tsvector('english', 'Big cats eat fish on Mondays.') 
               @@ phraseto_tsquery('english', 'eat fish on monday') as query;
 query
-------
 t
```

Note that the pluralisation and capitalisation of `Mondays` did not stop the match.

Use the `to_tsvector` function to create a parsed form of your content, which you can use for a GIN index.

```
postgres=# select to_tsvector('english', 'Big cats eat fish on Mondays.');
               to_tsvector
---------------------------------------------
 'big':1 'cat':2 'eat':3 'fish':4 'monday':6
```

Note how `to_tsvector` normalises the string (changing to lowercase, removing punctuation, removing plurals, and removing low value words like "on"). This means "eat fish if monday" would also match (since "if" is also a low value word). So you will need to add a second check using the `LIKE` operator if you only want an exact match. But this will run far less frequently than it would have without the `tsvector` GIN index.

So your query would now look like,

```
SELECT subcontent, content 
FROM A 
JOIN B ON (
    A.tsv_content @@ phraseto_tsquery(B.lang, B.subcontent) 
    AND content LIKE '%' || subcontent || '%'
);
```

NB. `phraseto_tsquery` requires 9.6+